# Unrecognized selector to an openfeint unlock achievement call

Tags: iphone, openfeint

I use the call as it is supposed to be used, but it causes a crash.

```
//someId is a correct achievement ID
[OFAchievementService unlockAchievement:@"someId"];
```

and I get the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[OFAchievementService unlockAchievement:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26f1c8'

I also get a warning

> warning: 'OFAchievementService' may not respond to '+unlockAchievement:'

How is one supposed to call this function? This looks correct according to examples.

Comment: What version of the OpenFeint SDK are you using?

Comment: Using OpenFeint version 12102010 (2.8). https://api.openfeint.com/

Comment: Pretty sure they changed the achievement API bits in 2.7 - I'd be tempted to check the API docs to make sure that method is still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
OFAchievementService *openfeint = [[OFAchievementService alloc] init];
[openfeint unlockAchievement:@"someId"];
[openfeint release];
```

instance methods begin with **`-`** class level methods begin with **`+`**.

With [OpenFeint SDK 2.7+](http://www.openfeint.com/ofdeveloper/index.php/kb/article/000026) try:

```
/* The following example shows how to unlock an achievement completely in one step without bothering to show a notification: */
[[OFAchievement achievement: achievementId] updateProgressionComplete: 100.0f andShowNotification: NO];
```

Comment: Nope. doesnt work. :( same kind of error . '-[OFAchievementService unlockAchievement:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x734b290'

Comment: what version of the OF SDK are you using?

Comment: Nice1. It worked. Thanks. Do you know how notifications can be set to the orientation of the current view?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following line just worked well enough for me (in `OpenFeint SDK` version **2.10i**):

```
[[OFAchievement achievement:@"achievementID"] unlock];
```